# How to get the data from external SQL Server database in SharePoint 2013 site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sql-server, external-content-type, external-list

What I want to do is retrieve the data from external SQL server database and bring it on the SharePoint 2013 site and show the graphs accordingly. So the data might be from different database tables. And data may be in large amounts, I tried doing it using **BCS connectivity** by creating `External Content Type`. But when I do it using tables or Views in SharePoint Designer 2013. It is giving me the error as,

> "Database Connector has throttled the response. The response from database contains more than '2000' rows. The maximum number of rows that can be read through Database Connector is '2000'. The limit can be changed via the 'Set-SPBusinessDataCatalogThrottleConfig' cmdlet."

Now when I change the threshhold limit to 50,000 using powershell, then also it is giving me the same error for 50,000 items. So I tried it by doing through Stored Procedure,  but there it is not able to create `External Content Type` because of the schema name, and giving the error as

> "Cannot retrieve SQL Server routine return parameter schema informaiton.  Invalid object name 'dbo.Information'.".

How to do deal with these type of issues. Does anybody have solution.

Comment: Lets take one step back; Why do you want it IN SharePoint? What does SP provide you that can not replicate (easier) with other technologies?

Comment: I want the data from external SQL server database.

Comment: So you have your data in one big truck and now you want to stuff it into a tiny mini-bus. Why? What does SharePoint do that you can not do now?

Comment: Yeah, as I have mentioned that if I try doing it through SQL tables or views it is giving me the error that mentions the throttling limit though increased and if I try it through stored procedures then it is not able to connect to SQL since because of the schema name, the name of my stored procedure is dbo.information and it is taking it as information. I just want to know is there any way other than this as I am new to the thing.

Comment: How many records does your stored procedure return in SQL Server? Are you using a temporary table in your stored procedure?

Comment: Do we need to write WCF or a sharepoint web service for this stuff?? Does BCS works too slow for large amounts of data.

Comment: "and show the graphs accordingly" - how is this being done? reporting services? custom application page? what?

Are you trying to import the data into SharePoint or just use the data to create your graphs?

You know you can use LINQ to connect to SQL, right?

Comment: Yes I am trying to import the data in SharePoint. How it is done by using LINQ. I am doing it by creating external content, and then creating external lists and then I will get the data from external list.